# Typeclass deduction error when using type constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have this function:

```
sTest :: (MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => m ()
sTest = do
  s <- get
  throwError "abc"
  put s
```

When compiling, I got a typeclass deduction error:

```
• Could not deduce (MonadError [Char] m)
    arising from a use of ‘throwError’
  from the context: (MonadState s m, MonadError e m)
    bound by the type signature for:
               sTest :: (MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => m ()
    at ...
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: throwError "abc"
  In the expression:
    do { s <- get;
         throwError "abc";
         put s }
  In an equation for ‘sTest’:
      sTest
        = do { s <- get;
               throwError "abc";
               put s }
```

If I change the `throwError` to throw an `Int` instead (and add a `Num` constraint) then the compilation is success:

```
sTest :: (Num e, MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => m ()
sTest = do
  s <- get
  throwError 123
  put s
```

Can anyone explain me about this?

**Update #1**

I create a new type for the errors:

```
data EvalError = VarNotFound
  | PlusParamsMustBeIntVal
  | FirstAppParamMustBeFunVal
  | OtherError String
  deriving (Show)

instance Error EvalError where
  strMsg = OtherError

sTest :: (Error e, MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => m ()
sTest = do
  s <- get
  throwError $ OtherError "abc"
  put s
```

But the compilation is still not success:

```
• Could not deduce (MonadError EvalError m)
    arising from a use of ‘throwError’
  from the context: (Error e, MonadState s m, MonadError e m)
    bound by the type signature for:
               sTest :: (Error e, MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => m ()
    at ...
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: throwError $ OtherError "abc"
  In the expression:
    do { s <- get;
         throwError $ OtherError "abc";
         put s }
  In an equation for ‘sTest’:
      sTest
        = do { s <- get;
               throwError $ OtherError "abc";
               put s }
```

Comment: To throw `123`, you need `e` to be Num. What do you need in order to throw `"abc"`?

Comment: I have a `ExceptT String m`, i.e error which has representation of `String`, so I need to throw a `String`. If I write down the signature using explicit types like: `ExceptT String (StateT L.ByteString Identity) ()` then the compilation is success. But I want a bit polymorphism here. It is possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
throwError :: MonadError e m => e -> m a
```

Here `throwError "abc"` makes `e` equal to `String`, so you need `MonadError String m`.

```
sTest :: (MonadState s m, MonadError String m) => m ()
```

Comment: I got this error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadError String m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • In the type signature:
        sTest :: (MonadState s m, MonadError String m) => m ()

Comment: Yes, this requires the `FlexibleContexts` extension, which is benign.

Comment: Yah, ^^. But if I want to persist the genericness of e, what else should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you want `e` to be a sum type with one constructor for strings? Then you could use a type class such as `IsString` with a `fromString :: String -> e` method. `throwError (fromString "abc") :: (MonadError e m, IsString e) => m a`.

Comment: I updated the question, I did something like you said. Can you take a look?

Comment: `throwError $ OtherError "abc"` should be `throwError $ strMsg "abc"`

Comment: @VũTô If `e` is completely generic, you cannot generate a value for it, because you have *no* idea what type the caller will request; the best you could do is take the error value as an argument, and throw that. (For example, `sTest :: (MonadState s m, MonadError e m) => e -> m (); stest eValue = do { s <- get; throwError eValue; put s; }`

Comment: Aha, I've got the idea. It can't be specific in the body of the function, because I'm using the genericness in the signature. Thanks both of you, dudes :)